# como sumar n array generados de forma automática

Tags: javascript

a lo mejor el titulo no diga el problema exactamente o mas bien como es.

en resumen tengo una tabla que genero según unos datos que obtengo desde la base de datos y otros que se deben ingresar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Todos los datos que se muestran son datos dinámicos, osea el primer valor que se observa lo tomo desde la base de datos, y según ese valor y otros se generan las siguientes filas y columnas.

aquí el código de la parte que genera los siguientes cálculos:

```
function Generar_Datos_inver(datos, interes) {
var anios_presupuesto = parseFloat(document.getElementById('años_proyectos').value);
var globalizacion = interes / 100;
var anios_dep = Number(datos.anos_depreciacion);  //VALOR DE BDD
var precio = Number(datos.adquisi_depre); //VALOR DE BDD
var elementos = new Array();

var aux = new Array();
var totales = new Array();
var totales_final = new Array();

var contador = 0
var contador2 = 0
var cadena = '';
for (var i = 0; i < anios_presupuesto; i += (anios_dep)) {
    for (var j = 0; j < anios_dep + 1; j++) {

        if (j == 0) {
            elementos.push(precio)
        } else {
            elementos.push(0);
        }

        if(contador2 <= anios_presupuesto){
            aux[contador2] = elementos[contador];
            contador2++

            if(contador == anios_presupuesto){
                for (let k = 0; k < aux.length; k++) {
                    totales[k] = 0
                }                        
            }
            if(contador2 == anios_presupuesto +1){
                for (let k = 0; k < aux.length; k++) {
                    totales_final[k] = Number(totales[k]) + Number(aux[k])   
                } 
            }
        }else{
            aux = []
            contador2 = 0  
        }
        if ((contador) <= anios_presupuesto) {
            cadena = cadena + `<td class="pre-d td_cant_inver"><input type="number" step="any" value="${(elementos[contador]).toFixed(2)}" readonly></input></td>`       
        }
        contador++
    }
    precio = precio * (1 + globalizacion)
}
return cadena;
 }
```

el problema esta en que necesito hacer la suma de cada columna, y lo estuve intentando y esta en el mismo código, pero igual lo pondré para que vean como estoy intentando:

```
if(contador2 <= anios_presupuesto){
            aux[contador2] = elementos[contador];
            contador2++

            if(contador == anios_presupuesto){
                for (let k = 0; k < aux.length; k++) {
                    totales[k] = 0
                }                        
            }
            if(contador2 == anios_presupuesto +1){
                for (let k = 0; k < aux.length; k++) {
                    totales_final[k] = Number(totales[k]) + Number(aux[k])   
                } 
                console.log(totales_final);
            }
        }else{
            aux = []
            contador2 = 0  
        }
```

Entonces cuando muestro por consola me da este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Obtengo 2 array, pero en este caso por que tengo solo 2 ejemplos pero la cosa es que podrían ser 3...4...5....n
y lo que estuve intentando era sumarlos en cada posición y que me genere un único array con la suma.

> la imagen de la consola no tiene los valores que aparecen en la primera imagen por la razón que le había hecho una captura antes y me di cuenta después.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es al recorrer los datos crear un `array` completo que guarde los datos por año y columna.

```
var a_completo = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < anios_presupuesto; i += (anios_dep)) {
    var a_aux = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < anios_dep + 1; j++) {
      ...
      a_aux[j] = elementos[contador];
    }
    a_completo.push(a_aux);        
...
}
```

Y una vez terminado de recorrer el bucle se suman los datos obtenidos. Para ello recorremos todas las posiciones de cada `array` interno (todos deben tener el mismo número de elementos) en todos los elementos del `array` completo.

```js
var a_completo = [[0,20,30],[10,20,40],[5,0,15]]; //ejemplo de resultado
let a_suma = [];
for (j=0; j<a_completo[0].length; j++) {
  let suma = 0;
  for (i=0; i<a_completo.length; i++) {
    suma += a_completo[i][j];
  }
  a_suma.push(suma);
}

console.log(a_suma);
```

**EDICIÓN** para sumar arrays con distinto número de elementos

En este caso tomamos como referencia el mayor número de elementos posible, variable que usamos para recorrer los datos, y preguntamos si el elemento tiene un valor o existe antes de sumar.

```js
var a_completo = [[0,20,30,40],[10,20,40],[5,0,15,3]]; //ejemplo de resultado
let a_suma = [];
for (j=0; j<4; j++) {
  let suma = 0;
  for (i=0; i<a_completo.length; i++) {
   if (a_completo[i][j] >0) { suma += a_completo[i][j]; }    
  }
  a_suma.push(suma);
}

console.log(a_suma);
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, los `array` si tendrán el mismo numero de elementos por eso algunas condiciones.
y utilizando tu código, me genera un error en el  `a_completo[i][j] = precio;`    error = `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: @DuvalAD parece que alguno de los índices no esta definido al construir el a_completo, es posible que yo no esté siguiendo correctamente la lógica, cómo los datos los implementas con un if, prueba en su lugar a rellenarlo en este if después de la variable cadena con a_completo[i][j] = elementos[contador];

Comment: Carmen, eso fue lo que intente luego, sigue el mismo problema, la única "forma" de que me muestre valores es cuando solo lo dejo `a_completo[i] = elementos[contador]`  con `[i]` o `[j]` juntos me manda ese error, pero los valores que envía siguen siendo los mismo que mi captura de consola de la publicación (2 array separados).

Comment: @DuvalAD Ok, es un problema de índices por el multidimensional, voy a editarlo para solucionarlo con un array auxilar.

Comment: mire si `a_aux[j] = elementos[contador];` lo pongo dentro del if donde esta la `cadena` me aparece esto por consola https://prnt.sc/sjiy8z.   y si lo pongo finalizando antes del contador++ me aparece esto https://prnt.sc/sjj184,....

Comment: El segundo es el correcto, pero parece que no todos tienen el mismo número de elementos, en ese caso el procedimiento de suma se puede hacer pero sería un poquito más complejo, ya que el valor del índice j ha de ser el de mayor número de elementos (supongo que en tu caso es equivalente a anios_dep) y antes de hacer la suma hay que preguntar con un if si existe el elemento a sumar.

Comment: la idea era tener un array con los array generados dentro `var a_completo = [[0,20,30,40],[10,20,40],[5,0,15,3]]; //ejemplo de resultado` pero prácticamente nunca se llega a eso, https://prnt.sc/skip89

Comment: lo pude conseguir, pero ahora tengo otro problema que esta puede estar vinculado a como lo estoy haciendo.

Comment: tengo un input que es "dinamico" osea ingreso un valor y me debe volver a calcular la tabla, https://prnt.sc/skl7uy , el asunto es que cuando le ingreso un valor lo que hace es que me genera otros vectores y se suman osea que si antes eran 2 array en 1 ahora seran 4 array en 1 y se duplican los valores, etonces siempre me hara eso de duplicar esos array. html:  https://prnt.sc/skl9fd     console : https://prnt.sc/skladm

Comment: @DuvalAD en ese caso lo que tienes que hacer es vaciar los arrays o volver a definirlos antes de volver a calcular la tabla para que no duplique valores.

Comment: me percate que solo se agregan los otros `array` si el `array (a_completo)` esta fuera de la función,
`var a_completo = new Array();
function Generar_Datos_inver(datos, interes){
.....}`
.en caso de que este dentro de la función me muestra algo así: https://prnt.sc/slw74k (si lo consulto por consola `a_completo`)
si hago para sumar me muestra https://prnt.sc/slwdqk.sera que me podrías indicar si esta de forma correcta lo que estoy haciendo o intento lo que dices de vaciar los `array` (aunque tampoco sabría como hacerlo, primera vez que hago esto) te agradezco montón por ayudarme.

Comment: @DuvalAD el array es mejor definirlo dentro de la función, eso hace que cada vez que se active la función se genere de nuevo y borre o vacíe datos anteriores, y lo recorres dentro de la propia función fuera del bucle que lo rellena,

Comment: olvide darte el visto. Muchas gracias!